# Squish sometimes fails to startApplication on the second test case in a Test Suite when running Valgrind

Tags: c++, qt, automated-tests, squish

I have a Squish Test Suite with two test cases inside.  **It runs fine normally**.

However, when **Valgrind** is enabled, the second test case fails maybe 50% of the time, with the error:

```
Script Error RuntimeError: startApplication() failed
```

I see in the log that Squish only waited 20 seconds between attempting to start the second test case and giving up.

Thinking that this is a timeout issue due to Valgrind running, I've tried increasing the following timeouts:

```
squishserver --config setAUTTimeout 600
squishserver --config setResponseTimeout 1200
squishserver --config setSoftExitTimeout 20000
        
squishrunner --config setAUTTimeout 600
squishrunner --config setAUTPostMortemTimeout 300000
```

I also call startApplication in the second test by requesting a much longer timeout

```
app = startApplication("MyApp", 600000)
```

However, none of these seem to increase the startup wait time reported in the log beyond 20 seconds.

Any advice on how to deal with a second Test Case that fails on startup when the CPU is heavily loaded (by Valgrind)?

--- EDIT ---

**server.ini** (local to each linux account)

```
[General]
AUT/MyApp= "/vobs/ui/squish_utils"
AUTPMTimeout = "20000"
AUTSoftExitTimeout = "2000"
AUTTimeout = "20"
ResponseTimeout = "300"
sponseTimeout = "1200"
```

**Unit Test output** (note :17 and :37 second timestamps = 20s wait time)

```
92  2021-11-23T21:00:17 END_TEST_CASE End 'tst_case1' End of test 'tst_case1'
93  21:00:17:224 Debug: Connection closed from 127.0.0.1:34460
94  2021-11-23T21:00:17 START_TEST_CASE Start 'tst_case2' Test 'tst_case2' started (tst_case2)
95  2021-11-23T21:00:17 LOG /vobs/ui/tools/MyApp/unit_test/suite_WS/tst_case2/test.py:42: Timeout set to: 300000
96  21:00:17:467 Debug: Connection established from 127.0.0.1:34494
97  RUNNERID: 163488749
98  21:00:17:470 Debug: Connection established from 127.0.0.1:34495
99  AUTID: 163488751
100 AUTHOST: 127.0.0.1
101 AUTPORT: 4322
102 RUNNERID: -1
103 QT_NO_GLIB
104 
105 21:00:19:236 Debug: SoftExitTimeout reached (2000ms). Some AUT processes are still running and will now be shutdown.
106 21:00:19:236 Debug: Trying to close process: /vobs/ui/squish_utils/MyApp
107 AUT stderr (163488749): QStandardPaths: XDG_RUNTIME_DIR not set, defaulting to '/tmp/runtime-build'
108 AUT stderr (163488749): INFO: Loading Qt Wrapper configuration from "/user/tools/LINUX/Development/squish/squish-6.3.1-qt59x-linux64/etc/qtwrapper.ini"
109 AUT stderr (163488749): INFO: Installing atexit() handler to catch AUT shutdown
110 AUT stderr (163488749): INFO: Use of native dialogs in Qt is disabled (if possible)
111 AUT stderr (163488749): QSettings path override to: "/vobs/ui/tools/MyApp/unit_test"
112 AUT stderr (163488749):
113 AUTID: -1
114 2021-11-23T21:00:37 ERROR /vobs/ui/tools/MyApp/unit_test/suite_WS/tst_case2/test.py:44: Script Error RuntimeError: startApplication() failed
115 2021-11-23T21:00:37 END_TEST_CASE End 'tst_case2' End of test 'tst_case2'
116 21:00:37:479 Debug: Connection closed from 127.0.0.1:34495
117 21:00:37:481 Debug: Connection closed from 127.0.0.1:34494
118 2021-11-23T21:00:37 END End 'suite_WS' End of test 'suite_WS'
```

Comment: The timeouts with same names are the same, regardless of if use squishserver directly, or indirectly via squishrunner (which instructs squishserver to perform the respective change). startApplication()'s second parameter however is the host name, so your startApplication() call is invalid. Is the squishserver that launches the AUT running on the computer where you executed the above --config commands? Can you please provide the contents of server.ini as well as the output of squishserver (or from Runner/Server Log) where the AUT killing is mentioned, including the timeout?

Comment: Ah, thank you.  The startApplication() call must ignore the hostname if only two arguments are given, since this works when not running Valgrind, but I fixed that call.  Yes, squishrunner is on the same workstation.  I edited the post with the server.ini file.  It does show a 20s timeout, rather than what we're requesting in our squishrunner code.  Note that a server.ini lives in everyone's home account, including mine and our "build" user that runs the builds.